# Xmpp protocol + ejabber server: Turn connection fails with feature-not-implemented error on IOS Application

Tags: ios, xmpp, ejabberd, xmppframework

I am using https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework xmpp framework for iOS. while trying to make TURN Connection I get below error for iq sent to establish the connection. while debugging the code i realise that the target client is sending feature-not-implemented iq when the received iq from initiator is not handled. but i am not getting why the below sent IQ is not being handled on target client?

SEND:

```
<iq type="set" to="smita1@dev.gungroo.com/38303823331368691199448799" id="2D376DBF-D437-48C8-B0FF-B10A5CD73240">
    <query xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/bytestreams" sid="2D376DBF-D437-48C8-B0FF-B10A5CD73240" mode="tcp">
        <streamhost xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/bytestreams" jid="proxy.dev.gungroo.com" host="10.212.103.159" port="7777"/>
    </query>
</iq>
```

RECV:

```
<iq xmlns="jabber:client" from="smita1@dev.gungroo.com/38303823331368691199448799" to="smita@dev.gungroo.com/278621573136869119737843" type="error" id="2D376DBF-D437-48C8-B0FF-B10A5CD73240">
    <query xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/bytestreams" sid="2D376DBF-D437-48C8-B0FF-B10A5CD73240" mode="tcp">
       <streamhost xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/bytestreams" jid="proxy.dev.gungroo.com" host="10.212.103.159" port="7777"/>
    </query>
    <error type="cancel" code="501">
        <feature-not-implemented xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas"/>
    </error>
</iq>
```

if anyone has got similar problem, please help to figure out why it is happening and how can I get it working?

Comment: Hi, Did you resolve this problem?
I am also getting the same error.

Comment: Too late, though! We get `feature-not-implemented` from Bob because Bob returns `NO` for `xmppStream:didReceiveIQ` delegate. He should return `YES` and process the `streamhost` request.